# Stop animation on SwiftUI button in a ForEach stack

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-animations

**Overview**

I'm learning SwiftUI with the #100daysofswiftui, im doing the day 32. its a simple game of flags I have and array with the countrys name and chose random the right answer

```
@State private var paises = ["Poland", "Russia", "Spain", "UK", "US"].shuffled()
@State private var respuestaCorrecta = Int.random(in: 0...2)
```

then I make the buttons with a forEach

```
ForEach(0 ..< 3){ numero in
    //right answer
    if numero == self.respuestaCorrecta {
        Button(action:{
            self.BanderaSeleccionada(numero)
        }){
            Bandera(imagen: self.paises[numero])
        }    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(self.GoodAnimationAmount),
                               axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
    } else {
        Button(action:{
            self.BanderaSeleccionada(numero)
        }){
            Bandera(imagen: self.paises[numero])
        } 
    }
}
```

if user chose the right button I do this:

```
func BanderaSeleccionada(_ numero: Int)  {
    if numero == respuestaCorrecta{
        tituloPuntaje = "Respuesta correcta"
        textoPuntaje = "¡Bien Hecho!"
        self.puntaje += 1

        self.GoodAnimationAmount += 360
        withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 5, damping: 1)) {
                             self.GoodAnimationAmount += 360
        }


        withAnimation {
                       self.TheOthersAnimationAmount -= 0.75
                   }


    }else{
        withAnimation{ 
            self.WrongAnimationAmount += 4
        }

        tituloPuntaje = "Respuesta incorrecta"
        textoPuntaje = "Has elegido \(paises[numero])"
    }

    mostrarPuntuajeMasAlto = true
}
```

to make spin the right answer

**The problem**

the problem comes with the change of values, if the next right button is the same like the last one the flag continues spinning so it spoil the right answer, when the right answer is another the animation just disappear, so im a little confuse about how Swift is working.

the best I can do now is remove the `.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 2, damping: 1)` but I would like to stope the interpolatingSpring when the countrys are shuffle.

```
func hacerPregunta() {
    self.GoodAnimationAmount = 0
    self.WrongAnimationAmount = 0
    self.TheOthersAnimationAmount = 1.0

    respuestaCorrecta = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    paises.shuffle()   
}
```

[image: example of the bug]

Answer (score 1):

When jump to next question, should update the correct answer **respuestaCorrecta = -1** instead random like this **respuestaCorrecta = Int.random(in: 0...2)**.

Comment: that may crash the app, te rigthAnswer must be 0,1 or 2 to be and option of the array.

Comment: @MisaelLanderos can you show me code in `BanderaSeleccionada` function